# Multiple errors and warnings from compiling the psych engine

Tags: haxe, haxelib

> Error: source/Achievements.hx:126: characters 30-54 : Warning :
> `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use
> `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
> source/MainMenuState.hx:73: characters 3-39 : Warning :
> `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use
> `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead source/PlayState.hx:341:
> characters 3-39 : Warning : `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated,
> use `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
> source/editors/CharacterEditorState.hx:93: characters 3-41 : Warning :
> `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use
> `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
> source/editors/DialogueCharacterEditorState.hx:81: characters 3-40 :
> Warning : `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use
> `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:145:
> characters 8-18 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:180:
> characters 8-18 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:221:
> characters 8-18 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:515:
> characters 8-18 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:483:
> characters 37-56 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:484:
> characters 31-47 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead. C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hscript/2,4,0/hscript/Interp.hx:646:
> characters 10-42 : Warning : Std.is is deprecated. Use Std.isOfType
> instead.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not errors, they're warnings. They don't cause any problems. You can safely ignore them.